# My dotless is not working on azure, internal error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dotless

http://s-projects.cloudapp.net/ProjectManager

When i run the site on my local machine from visual stduio it works.

I also noticed when looking at the .less file one local site, all the imports are compiled to one file.

on azure

the link in the html links to a file with :

```
@import"skin.less";@import"base.less";@import"site.less";@import"style2.less";
```

and the following i also found:

```
GET http://s-projects.cloudapp.net/ProjectManager/Content/base.less 500 (Internal Server Error) ProjectManager:13
GET http://s-projects.cloudapp.net/ProjectManager/Content/site.less 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: The Firebug Net tab is useful in providing full details for "internal server error" results via Ajax, what does it say?

Comment: I don't have that, but i removed the Bundle Transformer and used dotless directly. It still works on localhost, but when deploying it, it do not seem to combine the import "other.less" files, but instead makes the browser download the files side by side. Hence i can see the dotless error : variable @background-image-url is undefined on line 16 in file '/Content/site.less':  .This is defined in a file that is imported with import statement

Comment: So the error is somehow related to the server not combining the less files

Comment: Test it from IIS, not just IIS Express/VS. Most often the problem is IIS Express runs at the root level

Comment: Thanks. I found out to solve it. Not 100% sure where it vent wronge. But it must have been something with the setup of the bundle transformers. I will commit an answer with my setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
        //var jsTransformer = new JsTransformer();
        var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();
        var css = new Bundle("~/Content/css")
        .Include("~/Content/style.less");
        css.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
        css.Orderer = nullOrderer;
        bundles.Add(css);
       // bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/style.less"));
```

Above works.